# How to get from where the user is coming on the landing page?

Tags: magento-1.7, ecommerce-tracking

When a user comes to my website I want to figure out from where he/she came?

For example:

```
 1. Google or other search engines 

 2. Direct type  

 3. in  email promotions
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the referrer.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER')
```

you can observe the general predispatch event to catch it. `controller_action_predispatch`.
If there is no referrer then it's direct access.
If the referrer matches `google` then it's from google (Duh!).

For e-mail promotions you can include in the urls a GET parameter for each email campain and match it in the same event.